# Regex - Ignore Particular String In Capture Group

Tags: regex

I'm looking to capture the string between `www.my-website.com/buy/` and `-PERMANENT.html` if it exists, but am having trouble doing so. I'm unsure how to create a capture group that would ignore a consecutive string. My attempts have failed so far.

```
www\.my-website\.com\/buy\/([^-PERMANENT.html]*)

www.my-website.com/buy/fork                          (Capture fork)
www.my-website.com/buy/wand                          (Capture wand)
www.my-website.com/buy/ball-PERMANENT.html           (Capture ball)
www.my-website.com/buy/bike-PERMANENT.html           (Capture bike)
www.my-website.com/buy/base-PERMANENT.html-ball      (Capture base)
www.my-website.com/buy/wall-PERMANENT.html-glue      (Capture wall)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need groups. The *whole match* of this regex is your target:

```
(?<=www\.my-website\.com\/buy\/).*?(?=-PERMANENT.html|$)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/i8njEpwDYw).

Answer (score 1):

If your URLs are really that simple, you could go by lazy matching, like

```
www\.my-website\.com\/buy\/(.*?)(?:-PERMANENT.html|$)
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KYjRuX/1)